# BASH - backup retain

Tags: string, bash, design-patterns

I need some help with this - i have a backup retain and organize script 
I have a folder full of backups with the pattern like `ReportsBackup-20140309-12-00`.

there is what I need:

1/ Remove all the files and just let the ones from 04-00h 
    i have done like this

```
removals =\`/bin/ls | grep -v -04-00\` 
rm /mnt/backupstorage/$removals
```

How can I isolate the files based in the pattern `ReportsBackup-20140309-12-00` per year and month?

Answer (score 0):

Poorly worded question. I assume you want to keep all the `*-04-00` files and delete the rest

```
# set up some files
$ touch ReportsBackup-201403{08,09,10}-{04,12,20}-00
$ ls -1
ReportsBackup-20140308-04-00
ReportsBackup-20140308-12-00
ReportsBackup-20140308-20-00
ReportsBackup-20140309-04-00
ReportsBackup-20140309-12-00
ReportsBackup-20140309-20-00
ReportsBackup-20140310-04-00
ReportsBackup-20140310-12-00
ReportsBackup-20140310-20-00

# use extended globbing
$ shopt -s extglob

# list the ones to keep
$ ls -1 *-04-00
ReportsBackup-20140308-04-00
ReportsBackup-20140309-04-00
ReportsBackup-20140310-04-00

# list all the ones you want to delete
$ ls -1 !(*-04-00)
ReportsBackup-20140308-12-00
ReportsBackup-20140308-20-00
ReportsBackup-20140309-12-00
ReportsBackup-20140309-20-00
ReportsBackup-20140310-12-00
ReportsBackup-20140310-20-00
```

Comment: sorry that bit was done already what I need is delete all the files in the period of 3 to 3 months, I only want to keep the files of the present month and one month of 3 and 3 months, thank you for the help anyway

Comment: You really really need to make your question more clear. Please edit it.